# How to remove the default title bar on rebol?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, rebol2

How to remove the default  title bar on rebol?

[image]

Comment: I have never used Rebol but I think this may help: http://www.rebol.com/docs/words/wview.html. Look at "opts - Window options [no-title no-border resize] (must be: block word)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [rebol2](/questions/tagged/rebol2), use the `[no-title]` (clears the title bar) or `[no-border]` (removes the title bar) option:

```
view/options layout [button "Close" [unview/all]] [no-title no-border]
```

So far as I can tell, the same holds for [rebol3](/questions/tagged/rebol3).

```
view/options [button "Close" [unview/all]] [no-title no-border]
```

I'm not certain if this holds for [red](/questions/tagged/red) also, though it appears the window face [has `no-title` and `no-border` flags](https://dockimbel.gitbooks.io/red/content/v/v0.6.0/gui/View.html#window).

If you invoke `view` from a script, then the title is gathered from the `Title` attribute in the [script's header](http://rebol.info/rebolsteps.html#section-9), though you can override this with the `/title` refinement.

```
view/title layout [button "Close" [unview/all]] "My Other Title"
```